# Redefine type of variable in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

By using Python we can redefine string into dictionary.

**Example :**

```
var = "testing"
var = {'body': var}
print var['body']
'testing'
```

With Lua I want to do same . I want to convert string object into table .

**My try :**

```
> var = "testing"
> var = {'body', var}
> print(var)
table: 0x12b2930
> for i,j in pairs(var) do
>> print(i)
>> print(j)
>> end
1
body
2
testing
>
```

With above example I can fetch testing string with

```
> print(var[2])
testing
>
```

Above code is not fulfilling my requirements. I want to store the value `'testing'` with `"body"` key .
I want to fetch like below :

```
print(var['body'])
'testing'
```

Please help me on this

Comment: That example python snippet is incorrect. If you run those lines in sequence you do *not* get `'testing'` as output from the print. You get `{'body': 'testing'}` which is exactly what you would get from lua if you had something that pretty-print tables (which the built-in lua `print` function does not).

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry for that ..it is edited now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var = "testing"
var = {body = var}
print(var.body)
print(var["body"])
```

Comma in table construction separates table entries. So by specifying `{"body", "testing"}`, you create two entries with keys 1, 2 that are equal to "body" and "testing", respectively, since that is how you initialise a sequential array.

If you want to assign arbitrary keys to each value, you have to use `=`, as in `{key1 = "body", key2 = "testing"}`. Now you can access those elements in two ways. One is object like, using dot:

`tab1.key1`

And one is array/map like, using square brackets:

`tab1["key1"]`.

In the second example, you have to pay attention to quotes. If you use double quotes, you're accessing a key directly. If not (`tab1[key1]`), you're using value stored in a variable named `key1` as key specifier.

Answer (score 3):

The Lua code closest to the Python code is

```
var = "testing"
var = {['body'] = var}
print(var['body'])
```